# Морфологический парсер

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, парсер

Нужно написать на С++ морфологический парсер. Программа на входе получает предложение на русском языке, а на выходе, выдаёт информацию о том какой частью предложения является каждое слово. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно почитать информацию на эту тему? Может есть уже готовый код?

Comment: Надеюсь, за это задание вы получите бонус в несколько тысяч долларов. Задание, если делать его правильно, крайне сложное. Не сильно отличается от реализации искусственного интеллекта.

Одной проверкой по словарю вам не обойтись, так как омонимы.

Comment: Несколько тысяч - маловато будет :)

Comment: @klopp: так это ж только бонус.

Answer (score 3):

Тема эта просто огромная, вот для начала несколько ссылок:

- http://vallaam.livejournal.com/68186.html
- http://www.solarix.ru/for_developers/docs/morphology_analyzer.shtml
- http://starling.rinet.ru/morpho.php?lan=ru
- http://www.codenet.ru/progr/alg/morf.php

Можно начать с чего попроще - посмотреть алгоритмы стеммеров (ищутся без проблем). Или, например, посмотреть [проект Петрович](https://github.com/petrovich) на разных языках: склонение имён, отчеств и фамилий. Базовая работа со словарями и аффиксами там представлена вполне доходчиво, IMHO.