# Как работает Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

Можете описать относительно кратко но технически правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Кратко](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/324777)

Comment: Ответ должен быть развернут, а не ограничиваться одной ссылкой.