# Поиск запроса в тексте

Tags: php

Приходят данные от стороннего API - запрос и текст в котором нужно искать этот запрос. Кириллица.

Нужно решение, которое позволит максимально просто искать этот запрос, желательно без использования БД.

Все варианты которые я нашел ( Sphinx, ElasticSearch, Google Custom Search итд. ) предполагают что поиск будет происходить по БД, но данные которые приходят динамические и сохранять их так себе вариант. Возможно есть решение получше.

Comment: Пример текста и поискового запроса?

Comment: @Visman текст любого рецепта, и ингредиент из него, при чем возможно сам  ингредиент  будет с разными окончаниями, т.к. он идет от пользователя.

Comment: Стеммер Портера http://forum.dklab.ru/php/advises/HeuristicWithoutTheDictionaryExtractionOfARootFromRussianWord.html а дальше обвешивать регуляркой выделенные корни и искать совпадение в тексте.

Comment: Для английского текста поискать надо на просторах инета. Для русского возможно более новую версию найти тоже можно. UPD Да, для русского надо искать, так как в этом примере регулярки без учета юникода.

Comment: Возможно ссылки из этого ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/324780/186083 пригодятся.